# Get available groups on member count and appointment date

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get all groups (bands) which have a specific count of members and are available (got no appointment) on a specific date.

I have 3 Tables:

```
TBL_BANDMEMBER
ID | user_id | band_id | record_date
--------------------------------------------
1  | 10      | 1      | 2019-02-05 12:14:35
2  | 20      | 1      | 2019-02-05 12:14:35
3  | 30      | 2      | 2019-02-05 12:14:35
4  | 40      | 3      | 2019-02-05 12:14:35
5  | 50      | 4      | 2019-02-05 12:14:35

TBL_APPOINTMENTS
ID | band_id | appointment_date
--------------------------------------------
1  | 1       | 2019-02-05 20:15:00
2  | 3       | 2019-03-02 19:00:00

TBL_BANDINFO
ID | name 
---------
1  | ExampleBandA      
2  | ExampleBandB
3  | ExampleBandC
4  | ExampleBandD
```

So my question is, whats the best way to get for example all Bands which have only one member (1) and no appointment on 2019-03-02 in MySQL.
It should work for other counts and dates too and give back the name and ID of the band from the TBL_BANDINFO table.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? If so can you publish please.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
SELECT bi.ID, bi.name
FROM TBL_BANDINFO bi INNER JOIN TBL_BANDMEMBER bm ON bi.ID = bm.band_id 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM TBL_APPOINTMENTS a 
    WHERE a.band_id = bi.ID AND appointment_date = '2019-03-02'
)
GROUP BY bi.ID, bi.name
HAVING COUNT(bi.ID) = 1
```

> [**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7361b5925b03ff10cddc4058843cd7a9)